# how to change the font of a pdf generated from an html element using jspdf html method

Tags: jspdf

I'm trying to change the font of my pdf that is generated from my HTML element

I tried adding font, and setting `fontFaces` attribute and I changed `@font-face` CSS

when i log `doc.getFontList()` it shows the Poppins font

but when i try to generate the pdf it shows me [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pQKW.png)

that is my code

```
                    const doc = new jsPDF({
                      unit: "pt",
                      putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
                    });
                    doc.addFileToVFS("poppins-regular.ttf", font);
                    doc.addFont(
                      "poppins-regular.ttf",
                      "poppins",
                      "normal"
                    );
                    doc.addFileToVFS("poppins-bold.ttf", fontBold);
                    doc.addFont("poppins-bold.ttf", "poppins", "bold");
                    doc.setFont("poppins");
                    const elementToConvert = document.querySelector("#id");
                    console.log(doc.getFontList());
                    doc.html(elementToConvert, {
                      callback: (doc) => {
                        doc.save();
                      },
                      fontFaces: [
                        {
                          family: "poppins",
                          src: [
                            {
                              url: "../public/assets/poppins-regular.ttf",
                              format: "truetype",
                            },
                          ],
                          weight: "normal",
                        },
                        {
                          family: "poppins",
                          src: [
                            {
                              url: "../public/assets/poppins-bold.ttf",
                              format: "truetype"
                            },
                          ],
                          weight: "bold"
                        },
                      ],
                    });
```

that is my css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "poppins";
  src: url("../public/assets/poppins-regular.ttf") format('ttf');
}
#id{
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

The method ".addFileToVFS" of jsPDF require the file to be in base64 format. Encode your font file in base64 format and then pass the string for "filecontent".